# title position in legend in R plot

Tags: r, plot, legend

I use the following code to draw a plot.

```
x = seq(-20,20,by=0.2);
c = .2;
y1 = exp(c*x);
c = .5;
y2 = exp(c*x);
c = 1;
y3 = exp(c*x);
par(mgp = c(2,.5,0));   # to adjust dist of x/y label to plot, x/y axes to plot
plot(x,
     y1,
     type="l",
     xlab=expression(x-theta),
     ylab=expression(L(x,theta)),
     main="function");
lines(x,y2,col="blue");
lines(x,y3,col="green");
legend(x=-20,
       y=40,
       title=expression(L(x, theta)==e^{c(x-theta)}),
       legend=expression("c=.2", "c=.5", "c=1"),
       lty=c(1, 1, 1),
       lwd=c(2.5, 2.5,2.5),
       col=c("black","blue","green"));
```

I find that the brackets of $(x-\theta)$ in the legend exceed the box. Is there any way to move that expression down? I tried replacing the original legend function by

```
legend(x=-20,y=40,title.adj=c(0,.5), title=expression(L(x,theta)==e^{c(x-theta)}), legend=expression("c=.2","c=.5","c=1"), lty=c(1,1,1), lwd=c(2.5,2.5,2.5), col=c("black","blue","green"));
```

However, the expression appeared twice in the legend box.

Thanks!

Comment: Quick fix idea: It fits in the legend box if you increase the height of the display device

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to output the figure into a file: setEPS(); ... plot(); ... dev.off(); So I got no chance to increase the height (manually). I tried postscript(filename="abc",width=8,height=20); No matter how I adjust the height, the brackets are still partially out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it looks better without a box ( `legend( ... ,bty='n')` ) but if you really want a box, here's how you do it:

```
lgnd = legend(x=-20,
               y=40,
               title=expression(L(x, theta)==e^{c(x-theta)}),
               legend=expression("c=.2", "c=.5", "c=1"),
               lty=c(1, 1, 1),
               lwd=c(2.5, 2.5,2.5),
               col=c("black","blue","green"),
               # no box
               bty='n');

# plot your own box using the lgnd$rect as your starting point
params = lgnd$rect
rect(xleft = params[['left']],
    ybottom = params[['top']] - params[['h']],
    xright = params[['left']] + params[['w']],
    ytop = params[['top']] + 1)
```

Comment: Hi, when I run the code (copy and paste). it shows "Error in (function (xleft, ybottom, xright, ytop, density = NULL, angle = 45,  :   argument "xleft" is missing, with no default". Is there any thing wrong?

Comment: oops.  you dont' need the `do.call(rect,params)`.  That was causing the error.  (I dropped it from the answer just now.)